# Mounting a 32" LED TV to Dry Wall without Stud Support

Tags: drywall, diy-vs-pro, television

We're looking into mounting our current TV on the wall in the bedroom, however we've hit a minor snag, it appears there's no stud in the area where the TV would be mounted.

I've searched the wall using the 'magnet trick' and positioned the TV where we'd like it to go (opposite the bed) and it falls exactly between the edge of the wall (metal stud) and the wooden stud which is half way down the wall.

The [mount that I'm looking at](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012S4APK) (and that's pictured) includes two snap toggle bolts, and I've also looked into and found some additional spring toggles. The TV itself is quite light weighing only 11.0 lb or 5 kg.

Anyway, what all the preamble boils down to is, do you think it'll be safe to mount the TV directly to the dry wall using a combination of Spring Toggles and Snap Toggles and not mounting it to a stud? If so, do you have any tips or hints on how to do it safely? If not, do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you,

[image: Stud Wall]

*TV Real, Mount Photoshopped in at the correct scale*

[image: Room Layout]

*Approximate Room Layout (note the "tv" on the wall)*

[image: Spring Toggles]

*"Heavy Weight" Spring Toggles*

Comment: This question has been asked on this site many times before, and the answer has always been **no**.  At the end of the day, it's your TV. If you feel comfortable hanging it from a thin sheet of compressed gypsum between sheets of paper, go for it.

Comment: I'd suggest installing something with some structural strength bridging the two studs, and hang the TV from that. Or build/buy a cabinet and mount it into that. Or build/buy something else that you can set it on top of. Or consider a ceiling-mounted projection unit and a lightweight screen.

Comment: Are you saying that chunk of drywall is on studs 32" (80cm) apart? That is very suspicious as 1) that is too big a span for drywall, and 2) standard spacing is 16" (and the only other common spacing is 24")... I would bet there is another stud exactly between the two you found, which of course you could use for your mount. Try a bit harder with your stud finder, or try putting an exploratory finishing nail in. (Note: with only one stud in the center, I'd rely on the bulk of the weight being supported by the stud but still use drywall anchors of some type mostly for stability)

Comment: @gregmac you're completely correct, I tried a few small nails and found a stud slightly off center, though I'm still unable to locate it using the 'magnet trick'. Looks like I'll be able to mount it normally after all!

Answer (score 1):

Bridge the studs by using wood and connecting the studs and forming a ledge for the tv then to be anchored to
The wood connect the studs which should be 16" apart giving the strength of both studs supporting the wood between then screw the tv using toggle bolts long enlighten to go through the bridge to the drywall

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it flush, you can cut out a rectangle of the drywall between the studs and replace it with plywood or MDF of the same thickness and then attach the TV mount directly to the solid panel.